# Auto check radio button or auto populate text box

Tags: javascript

Hello I need some help with javascript please.

I have 3 drop down options, field IDs "eligible", "eligible1", "eligible3". 
The options for this drop down options is Yes/No

I then have a list radio button fields again the field IDs "eligible", "eligible1", "eligible3".

The options for these radio button fields are Eligible/Non Eligible

So the scenarios I am trying to create using the JavaScript is when, somebody selects "Yes" for the drop down questions then the radio button for the relevant field ("eligible", "eligible1", "eligible3") will auto select "Eligible".

Thanks
Joseph

Comment: It will be MUCH easier for us to help you if you would post your code and explanation of what exactly we should do to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, please make sure IDs are unique in your page.
Let's consider dropdown fields are 'select_eligible', 'select_eligible1'..etc
and for radio buttons: 'radio_eligible', 'radio_eligible1'..etc

The code below will check the radio having id='radio_eligible' if 'select_eligible' is set to 'Yes' by User:

```
<script>
function val() {
    d = document.getElementById("select_eligible").value;
    if('Yes' == d ){
      document.getElementById("radio_eligible").checked = true;
    }
}
</script>

<select onchange="val()" id="select_eligible">
 <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
 <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help